# python3 host not receiving STDIN nativeMessage sent by Chrome extension

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a simple Chrome extension that passes the current tab URL to a Python3 host script using connection-based nativeMessaging.
Here is prototype code:

https://github.com/mlewis1973/tab_URL_via_nativeMessage

After install_host.sh for host1 and loading the extension1, you will see that background.js in the extension opens a modal message window, and then after dismissing that you see that the Python3 script is being run since it also opens a Tk messagebox window.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
import sys

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
showinfo(title="Bad MF", message="TB is the GOAT")
root.destroy()
```

In host2 example, I make the Tk messagebox contingent upon receiving the nativeMessage:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
import sys

raw_length = sys.stdin.buffer.read(4)
if raw_length:
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    showinfo(title="Bad MF", message="TB is the GOAT")
    root.destroy()
```

Tk window does not appear, and it is clear from other debugging that sys.stdin.buffer.read(4) is returning 0.
Both extensions are sending the url the same way:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
        // Get current url
        url = tabs[0].url;

        alert(url);

        var hostName = "com.google.chrome.host.test2";
        port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
        message = { "url": url};
        port.postMessage(message);
        //port.postMessage(url);
        port.disconnect();
    });
});
```

Any advice on what I am doing wrong with sys.stdin.buffer.read()??
I have verbose debugging turned on for Chrome and there are no errors or warnings (except for the Tk deprecation one).

Oh fyi this is on MacOS.

Comment: The official example doesn't have `.buffer` for stdin.

Comment: the official example for chrome is a python 2 host script (maybe I am wrong, but I don't think there is a python 3 example in chrome docs). The mozilla example does include a python 3 host script, and evidently it differs from python 2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue above is due to the asynchronous native messaging using chrome.runtime.nativeMessage() and calling port.disconnect() before the Python script has time to read stdin.  If you comment out port.disconnect(), then it works (albeit with an error on the extension side). You can also add a couple of For loops to allow some time to pass before the disconnect.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
        // Get current url
        url = tabs[0].url;

        alert(url);

        var hostName = "com.google.chrome.host.test2";
        port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
        message = { "url": url};
        port.postMessage(message);
        for (let i=0; i < 100000; i++) {
            for (let j=0;j<100000; j++) {
                //
            }
        }
        //port.postMessage(url);
        port.disconnect();
    });
});
```

The host should probably reply back to the extension before the extension closes the port. Or just use the asynchronous chrome.runtime.connectNativeMessage():

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
        // Get current url
        url = tabs[0].url;

        alert(url);

        var hostName = "com.google.chrome.host.test2";
        message = { "url": url};
        chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage(hostName, message);
        
    });
});
```

sys.stdin.read() and sys.stdin.buffer.read() both work with Python 3 host scripts.